# place the last element from bottom to top of stdclass object array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
[questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [quid] => 1
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [quid] => 2
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [quid] => 64
                )
        )
```

And I was trying to move the value 64 at the top and then 1 and 2 will come.My code is

```
function sortById($x, $y) {
return $x->quid - $y->quid;
}

usort($_SESSION['questions'], 'sortById');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is the logic that defines a list in the order of `64, 1, 2`?

Comment: actually there is no logic.I have this array and simply I want to put the last element at the first.

Comment: `list($_SESSION['questions'][0], $_SESSION['questions'][2]) = [$_SESSION['questions'][2], $_SESSION['questions'][0]]`

Comment: And of course sorting doesn't work, because 64, 1, 2 is not a natural order.

Comment: That is not working.It gives me blank array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of [array_unshift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) and [array_pop()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) will do the trick. This will always take the last element from the array and put it on the front.

```
array_unshift($_SESSION['questions'], array_pop($_SESSION['questions']));
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/7ZhJ4)